# C#- jQuery DataTable - apply CSS styling Only on specific Title Header Cells of columns (Not the Cell Data within the Columns)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, datatables

Here is the information about my development environment:

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013

.NET Framework 4.0

jQuery-2.1.4.min.js

jQuery DataTables 1.10.7

Newtonsoft.Json.7.0.1

jQuery UI 1.11.2

```
<table class="table mb-none" id="InfoTable">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th><i class="fa fa-street-view     text-muted mr-sm"></i>DRIVER</th>
                                            <th><i class="fa fa-calendar     text-muted space-right"></i>DATE</th>
                                            <th><i class="fa fa-clock-o     text-muted space-right"></i>DUTY CYCLE</th>
                                            <th><i class="fa fa-exclamation-    circle text-muted space-right"></i>VIOLATIONS</th>
                                            <th><i class="fa fa-pencil text-    muted space-right"></i>SIGN</th>
                                            <th class="center"></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>


                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr class="gradeX">

..............................................
........................................
..............................
```

Our requirement is to apply certain CSS stylings to specific Title Cells of columns.

```
                var populateInfoTableJS = function () {
                    $('#InfoTable').DataTable({
                        "aoColumns": [
                                        { "sTitle": "LogBsonValueId" },
                                        { "sTitle": "UserID" },
                                        { "sTitle": "DRIVER" },
                                        { "sTitle": "DATE" },
                                        { "sTitle": "DUTY CYCLE" },
                                        { "sTitle": "VIOLATIONS" },
                                        { "sTitle": "SIGN" },
```

Could someone please tell me how to implement the code in such a way that CSS styling can Only be applied to specific Title Cells of columns?

Updated follow-up question:

```
                    var populateInfoTableJS = function () {
                        $('#InfoTable').DataTable({
                          "aoColumns": [
                                        { "sTitle": "LogBsonValueId" },
                                        { "sTitle": "UserID" },
                                        { "sTitle": "DRIVER" },
                                        { "sTitle": "DATE" },
                                        { "sTitle": "DUTY CYCLE" },
                                        { "sTitle": "VIOLATIONS" },
                                        { "sTitle": "SIGN" },
                                ],
            "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [0, 1] }],
            "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
                $('tr th:nth-child(1)').addClass('fa fa-street-view text-muted mr-sm');
            },
......................................
................................
```

I tried the code in the aforementioned code excerpt but it renders really poorly if you look at the image below ( Look at the strange compressed Driver column):

[image]

Could you please suggest how I could change the code to improve how the column header renders?

Comment: Is this really DataTables 1.10.7? The column option `aoColumns` [only exist up till DataTables 1.9](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns).

Comment: Yes, I added the following two JavaScript code lines: var versionNo = $.fn.dataTable.version; alert(versionNo); to the end of the populateInfoTableJS javascript function, and the alert box gives the version as 1.10.7

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"! And please, find a better title!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @jia-jian for his help.

One of my colleagues at work found the following solution:

```
var populateInfoTableJS = function () {
                    $('#InfoTable').DataTable({
                      "aoColumns": [
                                    { "sTitle": "LogBsonValueId" },
                                    { "sTitle": "UserID" },
                                    { "sTitle": "DRIVER" },
                                    { "sTitle": "DATE" },
                                    { "sTitle": "DUTY CYCLE" },
                                    { "sTitle": "VIOLATIONS" },
                                    { "sTitle": "SIGN" },
                            ],
                       "headerCallback": function (thead, data, start, end, display) {
                        $(thead).find('th').eq(2).html('<i class="fa fa-male text-muted space-right"></i>DRIVER');
                        $(thead).find('th').eq(3).html('<i class="fa fa-sitemap text-muted space-right"></i>DATE');
                    },
```

However, I do want to warn other developers that there could be problems if you programmatically make some of the columns invisible in the success section when you use the AJAX javascript function.  For example, if you want the column with the index value of 2 to disappear than the column with the DRIVER title will be applied to some other column that takes up the index value of 2.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a built-in method to do that, as stated by Allan (dev of DataTables) [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/29816/set-class-on-th-cell):

> Use a little bit of jQuery in `initComplete` to select the cells and add the classes, or use `column().header()` to get the cell and then a bit of jQuery to add the class.

What you could do is to set

```
var table = $('#InfoTable').DataTable({
    // Removed for brevity.
});
```

And call `column().header()` to individually add the class

```
var header = table.column(0).header();
header.prepend("<i class=\"fa fa-street-view text-muted mr-sm\"></i>");
```

Note that the `0` in `column(0)` is the [column index selector](https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector), you can pass in other types of column selectors too.

---

**Edit**

Seems like the following like in your code

```
$('tr th:nth-child(1)').addClass('fa fa-street-view text-muted mr-sm');
```

Is causing the classes to be added to `th` instead of `i`, see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rurnosoz/1/) for the proof. Consider changing to

```
$('tr th:nth-child(1)').prepend('<i class="fa fa-street-view text-muted mr-sm" />');
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rurnosoz/) for an example.

Comment: Could you please take a look at my updated question?

Comment: @CSLewis Sure, looking! Gimmie a sec to update the answer.

Comment: @CSLewis I've updated the answer. I believe adding `fa fa-street-view text-muted mr-sm` to `th` caused the rendering problem.

Comment: I'll post my response as soon as I can.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: @CSLewis no problem! You can accept your own answer so that those who may have the same issue can find it. :)